# Function to affect multiple form objects (checkedListBox)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple checkedListBox's on a form. For each checkedListBox I have a button to "Select All" items:

```
private void btnSelectAll1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
    }
}
```

Where each button have the same functionality just with checkedListBox2, 3, 4 etc.

Instead of replicating the code in each click-function, I would like to simply have a function which replaces the "checkedListBox" corresponding to the button. E.g. "btnSelectAll1" sends "checkedListBox1" to the function and "btnSelectAll2" sends "checkedListBox2" and so on.

Something like:

```
private void btnSelectAll1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectAll(checkedListBox1)
}

private void btnSelectAll2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectAll(checkedListBox2)
}

void SelectAll(strCheckedListBox)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        strCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are almost there, you only need to change `SelectAll(strCheckedListBox)` for `SelectAll(CheckedListBox checkedListBox)`

Comment: You might want to consider creating a user control that encapsulates both the button and the checked list box.

Comment: Camilo Terevinto, thank you so much, it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Control.Tag` property to store the right `checkedListBox` reference in each button:

First, assign the `checkedListBox` control references in `Form_Load`:

```
btnSelectAll1.Tag = checkedListBox1;
btnSelectAll2.Tag = checkedListBox2;
...
btnSelectAll10.Tag = checkedListBox10;
```

Then, create *one* event handler for *all* these buttons (make sure to point each button's `Click` event in the Form.Designer.cs file to this event handler):

```
private void SelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedButton = sender as Button;
    var checkedListBoxControl = clickedButton.Tag as CheckedListBox;

    // Do what you need with checkedListBoxControl... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, in every event in winforms the sender is the object that raised the event.

```
Button button1 = new Button() {...}
Button button2 = new Button() {...}

button1.OnClicked += this.OnButtonClicked;
button2.OnClicked += this.OnButtonClicked;
// both buttons will call OnButtonClicked when pressed
```

You can do this also in visual studio designer, in the properties window using the tab marked with a lightning flash. Simply select a function you have used before.

```
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    // now you know which button was clicked
    ...
}
```

Be careful if you let other items also call this even handler

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.OnClicked += this.OnButtonClicked;

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender can be either a Button or a ListBox:
    switch (sender)
    {
         case Button button:
             ProcesButtonPressed(button);
             break;
         case ListBox listBox:
             ProcessListBoxPressed(listBox);
             break;
    }
}
```

This switch statement might be new for you. See [Pattern Matching in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)